# current queue size in rabbitmq

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

i'm using amqp.node and i'd like to set up a system that will retrieve 1 message from a queue each second regardless of how many are in the queue.  i want to check the queue size before i `get` from the channel though.  how do i do that?

`consumer.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api')
amqp.connect('<my_rabbitmq_host_info>', function(err, conn){
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch){
    var q = 'message-queue'
    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false}, function(err, queue){
      console.log(' [*] waiting for messages in queue: %s -- to exit press ctrl+c', q)

      setInterval(function(){
       getMessage(ch, q, queue)
      }, 1000)
    })
  })
})

function getMessage(ch, q, queue){
  if( !queue ){
    return
  }

  console.log('queue %s has %d messages in it...', q, queue.messageCount)
  if( queue.messageCount > 0 ){
    console.log('getting 1 message from queue')
    ch.get(q, {noAck: false}, function(err, msg){
      console.log(' [x] message recieved: %s \n\n', msg.content.toString())
      ch.ack(msg)
    })
  }
}
```

i'm getting the same number for `queue.messageCount` each time *i assume* because i'm sending the same `queue` instance to the function each time.  how do i get the **current** `queue.messageCount` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make another call to `assertQueue` every time you want to get the current size. invert your code so that you call this every interval timeout, instead of only once.

```
setInterval(function(){

  ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false}, function(err, queue){
    console.log(' [*] waiting for messages in queue: %s -- to exit press ctrl+c', q)
    getMessage(ch, q, queue)
  });

}, 1000)
```

also - this seems like a bad idea to me. i would suggest a different approach. set [the prefetch limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to 1 for the consumer. then your code will only pull one message at a time.

also, this might help: http://dougbarth.github.io/2011/06/10/keeping-the-rabbit-on-a-leash.html - different language, but the concepts should translate to node

Comment: thanks derick.  i was able to implement a token bucket and use prefetch just like this in an example app.. WORKED PERFECTLY!